# Why is the get method not working in a loop?

Tags: python

This code should save the html of the pages. In the future, I plan to open each page and parse data from it.

```
import requests
```

from time import sleep
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

def get_all_pages():
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
# 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'https://ndetal.com/',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
# Requests doesn't support trailers
# 'TE': 'trailers',
}

```
params = {
    'page-url': 'https://ndetal.com/catalog/zapasnye-chasti/noblelift',
    'charset': 'utf-8',
    'hittoken': '1676964178_c781bda4eee604512a0a33f4b4847066777b3b8c874b5321c4e64c328a41016f',
    'browser-info': 'nb:1:cl:836:ar:1:vf:14qzoz81rywx03264pevhj:fu:0:en:utf-8:la:en-US:v:970:cn:1:dp:0:ls:169832776753:hid:386669881:z:240:i:20230221112312:et:1676964192:c:1:rn:670050072:rqn:3:u:1676964177877528558:w:1425x815:s:1440x900x30:sk:2:wv:2:ds:,,,,,,,,,5658,5658,1,:co:0:cpf:1:eu:0:ns:1676964175443:adb:2:pp:3629563401:rqnl:1:st:1676964192',
    't': 'gdpr(14)mc(p-1)clc(0-0-0)rqnt(3)aw(1)ecs(0)fid(400)ti(0)',
    'force-urlencoded': '1',
}

with open('link.txt', 'r') as file:
        src = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
pages_count = int(soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find_all('a')[-2].text)

for i in range(1, pages_count + 1):
    url = f'https://ndetal.com/catalog/zapasnye-chasti/noblelift?page={i}'
    print(url)

    r = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
    
    with open(f"data/page_{i}.html", 'w') as file:
        file.write(r.text)
    
    time.sleep(10)    
return pages_count + 1
```

def main():
pages_count = get_all_pages()

Comment: What is the value of `pages_count`?

Comment: If `pages_count` is 1 or less, then the `for` loop will never execute.

Comment: What is `get_all_pages()`?  I don't see any function named that.

Comment: Below is the full function code, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.